# How to get access token for Alexa Smapis in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, authentication, oauth-2.0, alexa-skills-kit

Is there any way to do get access token for Alexa Smapis in Flutter without the following command?

```
ask util generate-lwa-tokens --no-browser <scopes>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The ASK CLI function you're asking about is a convenience utility. You can always set up your own Login with Amazon client in Flutter to get the tokens. Here are the details.

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/get-access-token-smapi.html

Looks like someone created a package to help you use Login with Amazon in Flutter too (caveat: haven't tried it myself)

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_lwa

### Adding

The example in your follow-up question is a scope. It sets the scope of the permissions for the customer to grant to your app.

The example for that Flutter library uses the following to set the scope.

```dart
import 'package:flutter_lwa/lwa.dart';

LoginWithAmazon _loginWithAmazon = LoginWithAmazon(
  scopes: <Scope>[ProfileScope.profile(), ProfileScope.postalCode()],
);
```

Those variables are defined here in that package.
https://github.com/ayvazj/flutter_lwa/blob/master/lib/scope.dart

Hopefully you can figure it out from there. I know about Login with Amazon and how its token requests work, but very little about Flutter.

Comment: Thanks,but how can I add alexa::ask:skills:read this scope in this package

Comment: Editing answer above.

Comment: yes figured it out, used scope as profile:userid and got the required access,thanks